# KeyError when loading pickled scikit-learn model using joblib

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, joblib

I have an object that contains within it two `scikit-learn` models, an `IsolationForest` and a `RandomForestClassifier`, that I would like to pickle and later unpickle and use to produce predictions. Apart from the two models, the object contains a couple of `StandardScaler`s and a couple of Python lists.

Pickling this object using `joblib` is unproblematic, but when I try to unpickle it later I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/home/(...)/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 578, in load
   obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
 File "/home/(...)/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 508, in _unpickle
   obj = unpickler.load()
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1039, in load
   dispatch[key[0]](self)
KeyError: 0
```

The same application both pickles and unpickles the object, so the versions of `scikit-learn`, `joblib` and other libraries are the same. I'm not sure where to start debugging, given the vague error. Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: is the latest version of scikit is installed on your pc?

Comment: Can you produce a minimal duplicateable code?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The solution to this was pretty banal: Without being aware of it I was using the version of `joblib` in `sklearn.externals.joblib` for the pickling, but a newer version of `joblib` for unpickling the object. The problem was resolved when I used the newer version of `joblib` for both tasks.

Comment: hello @haroba I am facing same problem can you tell me which version you have to used ? i am using joblib-0.13.0 version

Comment: banal, but useful;)

Comment: You saved my day! Super useful. I had a very similar load error caused by numpy. Update joblib to equivalent version solved this. So - thanks!

Answer (score 15):

With me, happened that I exported the model using `from sklearn.externals import joblib` and tried to load using `import joblib`.

Comment: No more `sklearn.externals.joblib` in version `1.3.0`. My problem was the banal version problem of `joblib` among different computers.

Answer (score 8):

Mine was interesting. I was working with `git-lfs` and thus the files had been changed and joblib couldn't open them. So I needed to run `git lfs pull` to get actual files. So if you are using compatible joblib versions, make sure your files are not changed somehow!

Answer (score 1):

For me the same version of joblib was used to dump and load but I was saving the file under python 3.7.4 and attempting to load with python 3.7.6 which raised the same KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to load an XGB. I found out [XGB](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) is not compatible with other sklearn models, so I did the following:

```py
from xgboost import *
import joblib

def get_model(model_path):
    if 'xgb' in model_path:
        xgb_model = XGBClassifier()
        xgb_model.load_model(model_path)
        model = xgb_model
    else: 
        model = get_obj(model_path)
    return model 

xbg = get_model('Models/xgb_v1.pkl') # an xgb

tree = model = get_model('Models/dt_v1.pkl') # a decition tree
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to load years old joblib files, which gave multiple levels of errors, depending on the hack I used to bypass them.

With the increasing versions of joblib, the hacks stopped working and I had to create a conda environment specifically for `sklearn-0.23` as such:

`conda create -n outdated "scikit-learn<0.23"`

Afterwards, I was able to open the files and save them differently. This sometimes this means re-saving the data with non-sklearn joblib files `import joblib`; sometimes this means using `pickle`; sometimes this meant using `pandas.to_csv`.

The solution was specific to the data file being re-saved for posterity.